# XStream Linkedlist Error

Tags: android, xml, xstream

I have this XML file

```
<web>
    <listcuadrillas>
        <cuadrilla>
            <idCuadrilla>LUJAN 01</idCuadrilla>
        </cuadrilla>
        <cuadrilla>
            <idCuadrilla>LUJAN 02</idCuadrilla>
        </cuadrilla>
        <cuadrilla>
            <idCuadrilla>LUJAN 03</idCuadrilla>
        </cuadrilla>
        <cuadrilla>
            <idCuadrilla>XPRUEBA</idCuadrilla>
        </cuadrilla>
    </listcuadrillas>
</web>
```

And I have this classes

```
public class CuadrillaData
{
    public String idCuadrilla = "";
    public CuadrillaData(){}
}
public class ParametroData
{
    public LinkedList<CuadrillaData> listcuadrillas = new LinkedList<CuadrillaData>();
    public ParametroData(){}
}
```

I want load the XML file in this classes.

This is my loader code

```
File oFile = new File(sPath, sArchivo);
XStream oXmlParser = new XStream();         
oXmlParser.alias("web",ParametroData.class);
oXmlParser.alias("cuadrilla",CuadrillaData.class);
oXmlParser.addImplicitCollection(ParametroData.class, "listcuadrillas" );
```

But It dont work
This is the error

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: listcuadrillas : listcuadrillas
---- Debugging information ----
message             : listcuadrillas
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : listcuadrillas
class               : com.gic.horizontal.ParametroData
required-type       : com.gic.horizontal.ParametroData
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /web/listcuadrillas
line number         : 3
version             : 0.0
-------------------------------
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Just leave
`oXmlParser.addImplicitCollection(ParametroData.class, "listcuadrillas" )`
out. Since you have a tag `listcuadrillas` surrounding the list with the name of the field containing the collection, XStream doesn't need a hint (and is actually confused by it).